# Textbox Positioning Issues On Form Bigger Than Resolution

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this form that works perfectly fine on resolution 1920 x 1080 (mainly cause I made it using that resolution).  I read information about controls from a database (labels and textboxs).  This information tells me where to place the controls.  Like I said, on 1920 x 1080 everything is placed correctly.  When I go down resolutions the form is now bigger than the resolution so I added scroll bars.  Issue is that the controls are being placed as if the form that is visable on the screen is all that there is.  So if I were to place a textbox at location (4, 90) on the form on lower resolution it might place it at (100,90).  Y coord is fine, X coord is not.

Comment: That's why you place controls relative to the container.  Use Anchors and Dock properties, and TableLayoutPanels and FlowLayoutPanels appropriately.

Comment: @LarsTech I never actually knew about TableLayoutPanels.  Probably would have made this whole process easier.  I am going to do some more research on it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although TableLayoutPanels looks very nice in this case it would be a complete hassle and a waste of time to basically completely redo what I have done already.  If I were to have started fresh I probably would have used TableLayoutPanels.  Instead what I did was, since the `Form` was bigger than the resolution, I turned my forms `AutoScroll` to `true` (which I said in the question).  I then set the `AutoScrollPosition` to `(0,0)` on `form_shown` which makes the horizontal one go to the left and the vertical one to the top using...

```
this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0,0);
```

Since the controls information is based off of where they are on the screen  I just force the form's top left to be located in the top left of the screen and not off.  I also had to have an override for the `ScrollToControl`.  Every time a control was placed it would reset back to the center and would mess the placement up.  So I added this...

```
protected override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl)
    {
        return this.AutoScrollPosition;
    }
```